# Insert Trello.com Print as PDF in project

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdfpages

I have printed a few lists to pdf (on a4 pages) which I need to add as appendix to my project. It seems I can do this with `\includegraphics` or with `\includepdf` (from `\usepackage{pdfpages}`).

- **Includegraphics:**
  Prints the first page , but keeps the top and left margins intact. Doesn't scale the image however, so the right and bottom margins are simply cut off. (The way Trello prints lists, it simply puts them all below eachother, one card-width wide, so the right-side being cut off is not so much a problem. The bottom part is, however.)
  Also, it doesn't print any other pages than the first.
- **IncludePDF:**
  Prints all pages on top of each other, basically resulting in only printing the last page.
  It does print the page on the same page as the header, which is nice. However, the chapter caption and number are printed over the pdf itself.
  Also it sets the margins to zero so the page is inserted as-is.
  Besides that the page numbers are now gone.

I think the way to go is `\includepdf`, seeing the results I already "achieved". However, I'd rather not include every page manually, because even though this is only 3 pages I might go crazy and write documentation of say, 15 pages.

**MWE incoming**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    empty page
    \newpage
    \appendix
    \chapter{Trello Board}
    %https://trello.com/b/MN172Syh/back-to-school -> print this page.

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includepdf[pages=-]{trelloExample.pdf}
        \caption{Epics \& User stories}
        \label{apx:scrumboard}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So it seems that, up to the point where I simply added `\includepdf`, everything worked. And then I added the figure.

Comment: If you need to include multiple pages of a single `pdf` into your document, [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) is the package you need. Have you tried `\includepdf[pages=-,
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.8]{<path-to-file>}`?

Comment: Sorry, will add that. I already do have that package (and I think it's mandatory in order to use \includepdf?)

Comment: I have now, and it still prints only one page: the last. (also you seem to be missing a bracket after headings ;) ) . When loading I can see it printing things on top of eachother, and the figure label is then printed a number of lines below the chapter heading (which leads me to believe for every page it prints an "empty" newline), instead of at the bottom of the page (preferably the last page) (oh and i see that the page number has now moved to the upper right corner intead of centered at the bottom)

Comment: Your `\includepdf` should not be embedded in a `figure` environment!

Comment: it seems it shouldn't, indeed xD

I guess this works now, and I'll see if I can't fix the problems now that it's no longer inside a figure. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact you're using `\includepdf` within a `figure` environment.
You just have to remove it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    empty page
    \newpage
    \appendix
    \chapter{Trello Board}
    %https://trello.com/b/MN172Syh/back-to-school -> print this page.
        \includepdf[pages=-]{trelloExample.pdf}
\end{document}
```

<sub>You can note that giving a MWE speeds up the answering process `(-;`</sub>

---

> ↓ *Previous answer, written when no MWE had been given* ↓

This solution works for me:

- Compile following code in order to generate `dummy-example.pdf`:

  ```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
      \usepackage{lastpage}
      \usepackage{scrpage2}
      \pagestyle{scrheadings}
      \clearscrheadfoot
      \ohead{\texttt{dummy-example.pdf} --- Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

      \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
      \lipsum[1-13]
  \end{document}
  ```
- Include the this `pdf` into your main document via:

  ```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
      \usepackage{lastpage}
      \usepackage{scrpage2}
      \usepackage{pdfpages}
      \pagestyle{scrheadings}
      \clearscrheadfoot
      \ohead{\texttt{main document} --- Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

  \begin{document}
      empty page
      \newpage
      \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{scrheadings}},scale=0.8]{dummy-example.pdf}% <-- adapt the path to the document accordingly
  \end{document}
  ```

You should then have a four-pages PDF, including the previous 3-pages pdf, and with heading:

[image]

Comment: This works for me... The primary difference I see: `documentclass{scrartcl}` (I use report) and your packages `lastpage` and `scrpage2`... Could you explain what they do, and why I would need them?

Comment: if I strip your answer down to \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    empty page
    \newpage
    \includepdf[pages=-,scale=0.8]{test.pdf}
\end{document}

it still works (remove all other packages and change document class, and then had to remove `pagecommand` because it didn't recognize `scrheadings`)... What in the world am I doing wrong? I'll see if I can add an MWE of my own.

Comment: If this example work, it means you should provide a MWE in your question so that we could help you further. The `lastpage` package enables you to use `\pageref{LastPage}` in order to get the page number of the last page, and `scrpage2` is `KOMA-Script` package for tweaking headers and footers as it is explained [in the documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2). `\documentclass{memoir}
   \usepackage{pdfpages} 
  \begin{document}
   empty page
   \newpage
   \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},scale=0.8]{<PATH>}
  \end{document}` works as well.