# Insert PDF and put Chapter heading over it (pdf has whitespace reserved for this)

Tags: pdftex, chapters, pdfpages

Following up on [Insert Trello.com Print as PDF in project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339100/insert-trello-com-print-as-pdf-in-project)

I have now created a PDF that has a sufficient margin on the first page, and no margins on the following pages. All pages have sufficient margin for the page numbers (and they show correctly).

In this margin I want the `\chapter{PDF Name}` to show, and not (as it is now) have a nearly empty page and the pdf starting the next page. How do I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Epics \& User Stories}
\label{apx:scrumboard}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{scrumbordExport.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to do `\includepdf` twice:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\includepdf[
  pages=1,
  pagecommand={\chapter{Epics \& User Stories}\label{apx:scrumboard}\thispagestyle{plain}},
]{scrumbordExport.pdf}

\includepdf[
  pages=2-,
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
]{scrumbordExport.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While not entirely clean (I assume), it does the job. Thanks!